# ps3mediaserver: Network error when seeking 720p or greater video

Tags: ps3, media-server, high-definition, ps3-media-server

For three years there's been [a known issue in ps3mediaserver](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/issues/detail?id=206).

[Seeking, or trying to use the **go to** feature](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1953&start=10), on a video that has a vertical resolution of 720 or greater (i.e. hi-def) causes an error:

> A network error has occurred

The issue is documented and open on the google code homepage.

The [author doesn't seem too interested in fixing it](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/issues/detail?id=206). Has anyone come up with their own solutions?

Comment: Try alternative software? http://www.serviio.org/

Comment: The only only media server i know of is TVersity.